# Add UserControl to page From another class

Tags: c#, asp.net

I have page and call method inside my page. I want to add some control to my page Control (not page itself) inside that method.

My Default.aspx :

```
<%@ Page Title="Home Page" MasterPageFile="~/Site.master"  ...  %>

<asp:Content ID="BodyContent" runat="server" ContentPlaceHolderID="MainContent">
    <asp:PlaceHolder ID="PlaceHolder1" runat="server"></asp:PlaceHolder>
</asp:Content>
```

and Code Behind :

```
namespace Program
{
    public partail class Default : Page
    {
         protected void Page_Load(object sender, Eventargs e)
         {
              MyClass.Calling(this); 
         }
    }
}
```

my another class

```
namespace Program
{
    public class MyClass
    {
         public static void Calling(Page page)
         {
              Textbox txt = new Textbox()
              // I want somthing like this:
              // page.PlaceHolder1.Controls.Add(txt);
         }
    }
}
```

Is this possible?

Update: Thanks to @The King.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm sorry about my previous answers not working to you.. I just wrote it from my memory... Here is a working solution...  You first need to find the content place holder before finding your place holder...

**Note : Please use ContentPlaceHolderID and not the ID of the Content Tag...**

```
namespace Program  
{  
    public class MyClass  
    {  
         public static void Calling(Page page)  
         {  
            ContentPlaceHolder cph = page.Master.FindControl("ContentPlaceHolder1") as ContentPlaceHolder;
            if (cph == null)
            {
                  return;
            }

            PlaceHolder ph = cph.FindControl("PlaceHolder1") as PlaceHolder;
            if (ph != null)
            {
                ph.Controls.Add(new TextBox());
            }
         }  
    }  
}
```

Please refer to the revision history for my old answers...

Comment: Are you sure you have the name of control correctly "PlaceHolder1"...  and is the control available in the calling page...

Comment: Are you saying that default.aspx does not contain any controls except the master page control... It would be better if you could post of your default.aspx page...  See if my edit works for you.

Comment: i think my problem is masterpage. when i use page without it my function work correctly.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look : [ASP.NET Page Class Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178138.aspx)